# Pointer from Rust to C via bindgen: first element is always zero

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I use bindgen to generate a C interface for my Rust code. I want to return a structure that contains an `Option<Vec<f64>>` from Rust to `C`. In `Rust` I have created the following structure:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct mariettaSolverStatus {
    lagrange: *const c_double
}
```

which bindgen translates into the following C structure:

```c
/* Auto-generated structure */
typedef struct {
  const double *lagrange;
} mariettaSolverStatus;
```

the corresponding structure in Rust is

```rust
pub struct AlmOptimizerStatus {
    lagrange_multipliers: Option<Vec<f64>>,
}

impl AlmOptimizerStatus {

    pub fn lagrange_multipliers(&self) -> &Option<Vec<f64>> {
        &self.lagrange_multipliers
    }

}
```

The idea is to map `AlmOptimizerStatus` (in Rust) to `mariettaSolverStatus` (in C). When `lagrange_multipliers` is `None`, a null pointer will be assigned to the pointer in C.

Now in Rust, I have the following function:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn marietta_solve(
    instance: *mut mariettaCache,
    u: *mut c_double,
    params: *const c_double
) -> mariettaSolverStatus {

  /* obtain an instance of `AlmOptimizerStatus`, which contains
   *  an instance of `&Option<Vec<f64>>` 
   */
  let status = solve(params, &mut instance.cache, u, 0, 0);

  /* At this point, if we print status.langrange_multipliers() we get 
   *
   *  Some([-14.079295698854809,
   *         12.321753192707693,
   *         2.5355683425384417
   *       ])
   *
   */

  /* return an instance of `mariettaSolverStatus` */
  mariettaSolverStatus {
    lagrange: match &status.lagrange_multipliers() {
        /* cast status.lagrange_multipliers() as a `*const c_double`,
         * i.e., get a constant pointer to the data
         */
        Some(y) => {y.as_ptr() as *const c_double},
        /* return NULL, otherwise */
        None => {0 as *const c_double},
    }
  }
}
```

Bindgen generates a C header and library files that allow us to invoke Rust functions in C. Up to this point I should say that I get no warnings from Rust.

However, when I call the above function from C, using the auto-generated C interface, the **first element** of `mariettaSolverStatus.lagrange` is always `0`, whereas, all subsequent elements are correctly stored.

This is my C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "marietta_bindings.h"

int main() {
    int i;
    double p[MARIETTA_NUM_PARAMETERS] = {2.0, 10.0};  /* parameters    */
    double u[MARIETTA_NUM_DECISION_VARIABLES] = {0};  /* initial guess */
    double init_penalty = 10.0;
    double y[MARIETTA_N1] = {0.0};

    /* obtain cache */
    mariettaCache *cache = marietta_new();

    /* solve  */
    mariettaSolverStatus status = marietta_solve(cache, u, p, y, &init_penalty);

    /* prints:
     * y[0] = 0  <------- WRONG!
     * y[1] = 12.3218
     * y[2] = 2.5356
     */
    for (i = 0; i < MARIETTA_N1; ++i) {
        printf("y[%d] = %g\n", i, status.lagrange[i]);
    }


    /* free memory */
    marietta_free(cache);

    return 0;
}
```

I would guess that somehow, somewhere, some pointer goes out of scope.

Comment: [The caller must ensure that the vector outlives the pointer this function returns, or else it will end up pointing to garbage. Modifying the vector may cause its buffer to be reallocated, which would also make any pointers to it invalid.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_ptr)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the issue lies in your implementation of `marietta_solve`. Let's walk through line by line

```
let status = solve(params, &mut instance.cache, u, 0, 0);
```

You've assigned an `AlmOptimizerStatus` and all its inner members. Up to here, everything is kosher (assuming `solve` doesn't do silly things)

```
mariettaSolverStatus {
  lagrange: match &status.lagrange_multipliers() {
    /* cast status.lagrange_multipliers() as a `*const c_double`,
     * i.e., get a constant pointer to the data
     */
    Some(y) => {y.as_ptr() as *const c_double},
    /* return NULL, otherwise */
    None => {0 as *const c_double},
  }
}
```

You then decide to return a **raw pointer** to a `struct` that is about to get out of scope and get dropped (`status`). Inside, you have the `Option<Vec<f64>>` you are returning a pointer to.

As a result, this leads to UB - your vector is no longer in memory, but you have a raw pointer to it. And, since rust does not protect you against this when using raw pointers, no error comes out. The moment you allocate something else (as you do when you defined `int i`), you potentially overwrite some of the memory you've used (and freed) prior.

You can convince yourself of this with this [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc2a52b26a00909df5eef4f88806089d), where I have replaced the raw pointers with references to trigger the borrow checker.

In order to get out of this problem, you will need to forcibly cause Rust to forget the existence of the vector, like so ([**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cae4d404e1c10026fcea5d923c0e8e28)):

```
impl AlmOptimizerStatus {

    pub fn lagrange_multipliers(self) -> Vec<f64> {
        self.lagrange_multipliers.unwrap_or(vec![])
    }

}
fn test() -> *const c_double {

   let status = solve();

   let output = status.lagrange_multipliers();
   let ptr = output.as_ptr();
   std::mem::forget(output);
   ptr
}
```

Notice the changes:

- `lagrange_multipliers()` now destructures your `struct` and takes the inner vector. If you do not want this, you'll need to make a copy of it instead. As this wasn't the purpose of the question, I went with destructuring to keep the code down
- `std::mem::forget` *forgets* a rust object, allowing it to go out of scope without being deallocated. This is how you typically pass objects across the FFI boundary, the second option being allocating memory via `MaybeUninit`, `std::ptr` or other means.

And the evident gotcha: doing this without dealing with the memory leak we have created on either the C side (via `free`) or the rust side (by recombining the `Vec` and then properly dropping it) will, evidently, leak memory

Comment: `forget` on a `Vec` doesn't allow you to recover it unless you save its capacity. If you only save the `ptr` and the `len`gth, you need to do `shrink_to_fit` first to guarantee there's no excess capacity, and then do `Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, len)` to recover it. Or, my preferred solution, use `into_boxed_slice` + `Box::into_raw`, then `Box::from_raw` to recover and free it.

Comment: @trentcl Very worthwhile addition there. Do you mind if I expand on the second option in the answer (with attribution, of course)?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Thanks a lot for your answer. I'd rather not change `lagrange_multipliers` as a lot of functionality depends on it borrowing `self`. It's also important that it returns `Option` instead of `Vec`. The above code, with the exception of `AlmOptimizerStatus` is actually auto-generated, so I know the size of `lagrange_multipliers`. As a workaround, I currently define `langrange` to be a fixed-size array (`[c_double; N1]`) and then copy the data from `status.lagrange_multipliers()` to `lagrange`.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis Both points would be fine if you were not immediately dropping the `struct` immediately after returning. That's your core issue - you're dropping `status` before using the pointer, and why I suggested not borrowing `self` (your MCVE made zero use of it). You'll need to find a solution for this, whether it is keeping the struct as a member of another struct, or copying the `Vec`.

Comment: Sure, please do! I don't request attribution for making unsolicited suggestions, but do what you feel is appropriate.